# Possible to share logic among Components?

Tags: html, angular

I have several components that all do the same thing:

- display a form (the form varies though, so the HTML differs for each)
- capture the form
- validate and send the form using a REST API

There are certain things I'm looking to share among the components. For example, the forms all have a list of `RadioButtons` with the following values:

```
@Input() radioList: Object[] = [
    { label: 'Unsatisfactory', value: 1 },
    { label: 'Needs Improvement', value: 2 },
    { label: 'Meets Expectations', value: 3 },
    { label: 'Exceeds Expectations', value: 4 },
    { label: 'Outstanding', value: 5 }
  ];
```

Is there any way to share stuff like this so if I want to edit that `RadioList`, I don't have to do it four times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend class?

```
//property and property-level annotations (@Input) will be picked up by ancestors
export abstract class RadioListAwareComponent{
     @Input() radioList: Object[] = [
         { label: 'Unsatisfactory', value: 1 },
         { label: 'Needs Improvement', value: 2 },
         { label: 'Meets Expectations', value: 3 },
         { label: 'Exceeds Expectations', value: 4 },
         { label: 'Outstanding', value: 5 }
     ];
}

@Component({
    template: `<div>Comp1</div>`
})
export class RadioListImplComponentONE extends RadioListAwareComponent{}

@Component({
    template: `<div>Comp2</div>`
})
export class RadioListImplComponentTWO extends RadioListAwareComponent{}
```

Comment: So I'd have one component `BaseImpl`, and it wouldn't have HTML. I'd then create the 4 other components and extend `BaseImpl` and use the varying HTML?

Comment: Updated answer. No need in separate `BaseImpl`. Abstract class already has property and annotation. Any class that extends `RadioListAwareComponent` would have access to `radioList` AND that property can be used as input. Please note, class level annotations (`@Component`) cannot be extended in angular2 (i.e. you cannot share same inline template).

Comment: So I would make one class (not a `@Component`), and then still create 4 components which extend that class?

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own factory and inject it into your controller https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers